# Making a Javascript filebrowser

Tags: javascript, java

I'm having difficulty trying to debug a Javascript function.This is being run from a TomCat 7.0 Servlet so I've had to write it in Java so I apologize for the poor styling. The actual Java file displays the contents of a directory to a browser, and by clicking on the div with the id="foldername" it should pass that value to the URL reload the page for that folder. The only problem is that the java script keeps giving me the problem listed below.

```
<head></head><body><script> function explore(s){ //Trying to make this function work keeps throwing Uncaught Type Error: cannot read property 'id' of null
var x = document.getElementById(s).id;
var newUrl= document.URL.concat(x);
window.location = newUrl; window.alert(x)}</script><list>
<li id="bin"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(bin)">+</div> bin</li>
<li id="conf"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(conf)">+</div> conf</li>
<li id="lib"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(lib)">+</div> lib</li>
<li id="LICENSE"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(LICENSE)">+</div> LICENSE</li>
<li id="logs"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(logs)">+</div> logs</li>
<li id="NOTICE"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(NOTICE)">+</div> NOTICE</li>
<li id="temp"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(temp)">+</div> temp</li>
<li id="tomcat.ico"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(tomcat.ico)">+</div> tomcat.ico</li>
<li id="Uninstall.exe"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(Uninstall.exe)">+  </div> Uninstall.exe</li>
<li id="webapps"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(webapps)">+</div>    webapps</li>
<li id="work"><div id="plus" onclick="explore(work)">+</div> work</li>
</list><FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></FORM></body>
```

Comment: `"I've had to write it in Java..."` -- what do you mean by "write it in Java"? It looks completely like JavaScript to me.

Comment: Sorry this is running off of a TomCat 7.0 Serverlet I'll edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be passing strings to your function  as `getElementById` expects a string id:

```
explore('LICENSE');
```

apply this to all your calls to the `explore` function (enclose the parameter in single quotes). otherwise javascript will treat the parameter as a variable, and since you are not declaring those variables, all functions are receiving `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the code in `onclick` is actual JavaScript code.  Thus `explore(Uninstall.exe);` is trying to find the object `exe` stored in `uninstall`.  You should use quotes here: `explore('Uninstall.exe');`.  Same goes for all of them.

By the way, Java is completely irrelevant here, you should learn the different between Java and JavaScript.